# How to reduce a polynomial over an extension field (with or without MAGMA)

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, extension-field, magma-cas

I have the elements $u^{4770}$ and $u^{7489}$ lying in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{29^3} = \mathbb{F}_{29}[u]$ where $u^3+2u+27=0$. I'd like to find equivalent values with lower degrees so that I can work with them more easily, but I don't know how to do this. I know that in theory, I could do the following:

\begin{align*}
u^{4770} &= u^{4767}*(-2u-27) \\
\end{align*}
and keep on reducing the highest power of $u$ until I get something reasonable. This seems like a lot of work, and I'm hoping there's a more clever way of doing this.

I do have access to MAGMA programming language, so if there's a way to do it through that, I'd welcome that as a solution as well.

Comment: Square-and-multiply is better. Keep on squaring: $u^2=u^2$, $u^4=u\cdot u^3=u(-2u+2)=-2u^2+2u$, $u^8=(u^4)^2=4(u^2-u)^2=\cdots$, $u^{16}=(u^8)^2$, $u^{32}=(u^{16})^2$. Build a look-up-table of powers like $u^{64}$, $u^{128},\ldots,u^{4096}$ written as quadratic polynomials of $u$. That's thirteen entries, so trivial on a computer. Then you can calculate 
$$u^{4770}=u^{4096+512+128+32+2}=u^{4096}\cdot u^{512}\cdot u^{128}\cdot u^{32}\cdot u^2.$$ That is, four more multiplications and reductions modulo that cubic.

Comment: The general [square-and-multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) can also be organized differently. But if you plan on doing a lot of arithmetic with this field, then you probably benefit from having that table (up to $u^{16384}$). The element $u$ is actually a primitive element of this field. For even more speed it may be better to build and store the full discrete logarithm tables of all the $29^3-1=24388$ distinct powers of $u$.

Comment: In Magma, define your field F<u> := FiniteField(29,3); and check your minimal polynomial is what you want. Turn off PowerPrinting with PowerPrinting(F, false); and type your element. It will give it as a sum of powers of u less than 3.

Answer (score 1):

In Magma, the intrinsic `Eltseq` can be used to return the coefficients of an element of an extension field considered as a vector over its base field. For your example:

```
> F<u> := ext<GF(29) | Polynomial([27,2,0,1])>;
> x := u^4770;
> x;
u^4770
> Eltseq(x);
[ 26, 10, 12 ]
> x2 := 26 + 10*u + 12*u^2;
> x2;
u^4770
> x2 eq x;
true
```